# Difference beetwen install GEM and Copy and IMPORT the JS file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-select2

I have the desire to know the diference between copy the JS and SASS file and import in the application.js and application.css and install a GEM...

Specifically I would like to install select2, could there be any performance difference in the implementation of plugin or something?

Answer (score 1):

It is ideal to use gemified versions of JavaScript code from open source projects such as jQuery because this gives you the advantage of RubyGems as a package manager. The jquery-ui-rails gem from Jo Liss is an excellent example.

Unfortunately, few JavaScript projects are intended solely for Rails so there seldom is a gemified version of the JavaScript. Instead, the files are offered for downloading or from a content delivery network as external scripts.

[check this](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-javascript-include-external.html)